# Google Sign-in inside Android Library Project

Tags: android, google-signin

I currently use sign-in with Google+ in a library project that's shared among several apps and I'm trying to migrate this to Google Sign-in. I accept that I'll have to have part of it in each project, so it can have the proper JSON file, etc..., but I can't even get Android Studio to find the GoogleSignInOptions class after adding this to the library's Gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
```

It cannot find "GoogleSignInOptions". What am I missing?

Comment: That first line contains all the rest of those... If you only want that class, it's in the [`auth`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions) package.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it still doesn't find it, which makes me think I'm missing something. =/

Comment: Did you sync the Gradle file? Clean and Rebuild the project?

Comment: Yes. I did a clean, a sync, a rebuild, but it still says, `error: cannot find symbol class GoogleSignInOptions`

Comment: When you got the error "cannot find google-services.json", you have to actually download that file from the Developer console and add to your library

Comment: How can I add it to the library? The library has a different package name since it's shared between several apps?

Comment: SO has scolded me and suggested to [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120631/discussion-between-nicole-borrelli-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 0):

You added this?

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' 

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: When I include `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` then it reports it cannot find `google-services.json`, since this has to be applied to the app. This is a library project which will have an abstract class that's extended.

Comment: google-services.json you can download from Firebase or older Firebase brother.